# Объявлять переменную внутри main или вне

Tags: c

В чем разница между этими двумя вариантами? Только область видимости или есть ещё какие-то подводные? Есть ли различия между этими вариантами в плане памяти? И заодно - насколько глобальными будут переменные объявленные вне main - в рамках одного файла или всех?

Понимаю, что вопрос очень банальный, но очень уж лень читать уже в миллионный раз про переменные в разных языках.

```
int main() {
    int foo;
}
```

```
int foo;

int main() {
}
```

Comment: когда Вы создаете внутри main, то переменная будет создана на стеке и видимость будет внутри main. Во втором случае - переменная "глабальная" и создается совсем в другом месте памяти.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тоже отвечу.

В C и C++ если переменная объявляется в теле функции, то она размещается в стеке, во фрейме данной функции. Это так назывемая *локальная переменная*. Т.к. фрейм создаётся в момент вызова функции и уничтожается в момент возврата из неё (со всеми локальными переменными и переменными-параметрами функции), то речь идёт не только об области видимости, но и о времени жизни локальной переменной. Локальная переменная существует, пока выполняется функция. Также локальная переменная не может быть импортирована/экспортирована.

Если переменная объявляется вне тела любой из функций, то она размещается в секции данных приложения или динамической библиотеки (в зависимости от того, что компилируется). Это - *глобальная переменная*. Она создаётся, когда загружается приложение или библиотека и существует до тех пор, пока приложение не завершится, или динамическая библиотека не будет выгружена. Глобальная переменная доступна для обращения из разных функций, а также может быть импортирована из другого модуля или экспортирована для других модулей.

Answer (score 1):

Могу быть неточным, но отвечу.

Разница только в области видимости переменной.

Насколько мне известно, в плане памяти разницы нет в том плане, что и там и там переменная, но есть разница в том, что одна будет жить вечно - это не ссылка и не указатель, а статическая память.

Видна глобальная переменная будет там, где ты включишь свой файл с исходником. `#include "main.h"`